# detect strings that both includes and excludes certain word (with stringr package)

Tags: r, regex, string

Newbie here and couldn't find an answer to my question. I have string observations in my string variable and try to detect MS OR MA OR Master but exclude MBA:

```
input <- c("Master of Business Administration (MBA) program", "MS, MA, Master", "Master")
```

desired output with `str_detect`:

```
False, True, True
```

Edit: this worked for me now:

```
str_detect(input, "\\bMS\\b|\\bMaster\\b|\\bMA\\b") & !str_detect(input,"\\bMBA\\b")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what are you trying to "detect"? You have an input with length 3 and a desired output with length 4.

Comment: also, supply the input `input` to your `str_detect()` function, and not `c`.... for e.g.,`str_detect(input, "(?!.*MBA)\\bMS\\b|\\bMaster\\b|\\bMA\\b") ` returns `TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Comment: apologies, reframed the question for future help seekers. Thanks again for your rapid answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a single PCRE pattern (you need to use `grepl` with `perl=TRUE`):

```
> grepl('^(?!.*\\bMBA\\b).*\\b(?:Master|MA)\\b', input, perl=TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZawhs/1). NOTE that you may use the same pattern with `str_detect`:

```
> str_detect(input, '^(?!.*\\bMBA\\b).*\\b(?:Master|MA)\\b')
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\\bMBA\\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a whole word `MBA` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars from the start of the string (add `(?s)` at the pattern start to enable multiple line input)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\\b(?:Master|MA)\\b` - a whole word `Master` or `MA`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your logical conditions:

```
library(stringr)

input <- c("Master of Business Administration (MBA) program", "MS, MA, Master", "Master")

(str_detect(input, "Master") & !str_detect(input, "MBA"))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```